# My discord.py script runs multiple instances but i don't know why

Tags: python, discord, raspberry-pi, discord.py, raspberry-pi4

[image]i run my discord.py code on my raspberry but sometimes it logs in again, someone from told me that is because he reconnected. Someone also told me you can't have multiple instances running but in my log it is. my code prints the length of a list every 2 minutes (the extra time is the time of requests scraping sites) but when he logs in again(on its own without me doing anything) for a second time whilst my bot is running i think he doesn't reconnect but he starts a new instance because in the terminal the times are shorter than 2 minutes which means there are multiple running at once, how do i fix this? Also after some time the bot just goes offline from discord and doesn't respond to messages anymore while the code is still running.

Comment: If the problem is that multiple instances are running at the same time, why not run only one instance? It seems like you answered your own question.

Comment: The problem is i don't run it myself, i think discord.py reconnects if they are disconnected but the old instance is still running which results in 2 running instances. It doesn't get run again by me. I basically can't control it i think.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but one:
You can check if the last log is more than 2 minutes old, if no then terminate your script and if yes let it continue working. So there should be only one active remain.

Comment: Hi! I have been doing that today but that is really inefficient because i basically can't run my bot if im not home, this also should be solveable.